# Model for small signal - 3 transistors JFET

Tags: fet, jfet

Could you tell me if the models for small signs are well made? And if they were not, you could tell me what I missed, please? Thanks.
[image]

\$V_{dd}=17 \,V\$

\$IDSS= 8 \,mA\$

\$V_P=-3\$

\$r0=30 k\$

\$cgs=5 pF\$

\$cgd=2 pF\$

\$R_L=10 k\$

\$R_G\, (resistance \,\,of\,\, the\,\, input \,\,signal) = 100 k\$

For the first transistor:
[image]

For the second transistor:
[image]

For the third transistor:
[image]

Comment: The drain of q3 is at ac ground, other than that it looked good to me

Comment: @sstobbe I do not understand. What do I have to correct? Could you make the circuit corrected, please? It would be a great help.

Comment: Hi it's a simple fix, just add a connection from the drain to ground on your third transistor schematic

Comment: @sstobbe And the Vout of the third transistor is well designed? I did not know what to put in their terminals.

Comment: The vout is correct, looking at the very original schematic there is also Rl in parallel with source resistor you have drawn

Comment: The +vi is correct, the negative reference for vi is  ground not the source terminal

Comment: @sstobbe Why do I have to draw the RL resistance? I have seen solved problems, where when calculating the gain of only one transistor in the circuit, the internal resistance and the load resistance were set. But in the problems that were to solve with more than one transistor, we no longer put RG and RL (we only put to calculate the gain, the input impedance, the output impedance of the whole circuit).

Comment: Yes its a matter of personal preference, if you don't consider interstage loading and source and load resistance, you need to calculate in addition to Av, Ri and Ro for each stage

Comment: @sstobbe I did not realize it. In this case I do not have to use the internal resistance of the input signal or the load resistance, right? I only use the load resistance and the internal resistance when I join the three models for small signals and calculate the gain, the input impedance and the output impedance for the complete circuit. For each stage, I do not need RL and RG right?

Comment: @sstobbe If what I've said above checks out (if you think it's right) then the models for small signs are well made? (Except for the Q3 drain that has to be connected to ground)